# "ecryptfs-mount-private" returns "fopen: No such file or directory"

Tags: mount, password, ecryptfs

Recently, we've rebooted server and got ecryptfs mount fail:

> ...
>   Signature not found in user keyring
>   Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'
>   user@host:~$

Could that be because of password change?

Although,

```
1. There's no mount password
2. We might have login password
```

When trying to recover mount directory, it outputs:

```
user@host:~$ ls
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt
user@host:~$ ecryptfs-mount-private
Enter your login passphrase:
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
ERROR: Your passphrase is incorrect
Enter your login passphrase:
user@host:~$ sudo ecryptfs-mount-private
[sudo] password for user:
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [ad21fabcda6abfeab] into the user session keyring
fopen: No such file or directory
user@host:~$
```

So, as you can see, it shows such strange error: `fopen: No such file or directory` and, also, when running `ecryptfs-mount-private` without `sudo` - it fails.
When mounting folder using `ecrypts-recover-private` and login password it mounts it in temporary folder like a charm.
Also, we've tried to `ecryptfs-rewrap-password` and it doesn't work **without** `sudo`. So, using `sudo ecryptfs-rewrap-password` succeeded in rewrapping, but after reboot the same situation persists.

All in all, what could this be; how to fix this auto mount encrypted home directory at login?

Comment: What was in syslog (or dmesg) right after it said *"Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs"*?

Comment: @Xen2050 What a shame. I've just ignored this message because of some fear that files might be gone. You're right. That would be a right way to go. By the way, an author could add some message pointing that there's no permissions etc.

Comment: Logfiles can get saved or rotated or deleted, but that shouldn't happen right away. Also, many of the ecryptfs executables are bash scripts than can be examined and even ran one line at a time if you wanted, to see exactly what line's failing, hopefully that might help too. A quick `less $(which ecryptfs-mount-private)` works

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, log had this message. Checked with `sudo grep "Failed to detect wrapped" -r "/var/log/"` and an output had `/var/log/auth.log.1:Jan 11 18:31:58 host login[3739]: Failed to detect wrapped passphrase version: Permission denied` Thank you. It's one of those times when log checking is definitely necessary and it would saved time.

Comment: I keep a terminal open with tail -f showing new log messages, just in case. zgrep might be handy in case the logs get zipped too. If my answer's useful, do upvote it or even select it as correct (FYI [selecting your own answer as correct does not award any reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up an ecryptfs private folder, then removed the r & w permission from the wrapped-passphrase file to test... If you had checked the syslog right after seeing the message

```
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
```

You would have seen lines like this:

Jan 15 00:21:48 sys ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Failed to detect wrapped passphrase version: ***Permission denied***
Jan 15 00:21:48 sys ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: ***Error*** attempting to unwrap passphrase ***from file [/home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]***; rc = [-13]

Together those would be a pretty strong arrow pointing to check the permissions of the ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase file. (No sudo or strace required)

All in all, just make sure you're running `ecryptfs-mount-private` command as same user's directory you're trying to mount and `wrapped-passphrase` file has **-rw-------** or (**600**) permissions and same owner as encrypted directory.

Answer (score 1):

In short, user's file `wrapped-passphrase` had wrong permissions(should be `-rw------- user user`, were `-rw------- root root`).

Ran `ecryptfs-mount-private` command(entered login password) using `strace` like:

```
strace -o /tmp/strace.log -e trace=file ecryptfs-mount-private
```

Contents of `/tmp/strace.log`:

```
user@host:~$ sudo strace -o /tmp/strace.log -e trace=file ecryptfs-mount-private
[sudo] password for user:
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [3ab5cd8e5f8c5acb] into the user session keyring
fopen: No such file or directory
user@host:~$ cat /tmp/strace.log
execve("/usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private", ["ecryptfs-mount-private"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getcwd("/home/user", 4096)                = 9
open("/usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private", O_RDONLY) = 3
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3872, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
stat("/home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapping-independent", 0x7fff65e61c30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3873, si_uid=0, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
stat("/home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=58, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user/.ecryptfs/Private.sig", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=34, ...}) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3874, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
stat("/usr/local/sbin/stty", 0x7fff65e61c40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/stty", 0x7fff65e61c40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/stty", 0x7fff65e61c40)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/stty", 0x7fff65e61c40)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/stty", 0x7fff65e61c40)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/stty", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=72496, ...}) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3875, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3876, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3877, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3878, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3879, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3880, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=68, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3881, si_uid=0, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

So, we see that there's not enough information. Ran the same command(entered login password), but with flag `-f` to trace child processes and using **root's** rights:

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/strace2.log -f -e trace=file ecryptfs-mount-private`
```

Part of contents of `/tmp/strace2.log` file:

```
...
3963  open("/root/.ecryptfsrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3963  open("/home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase", O_RDONLY) = 3
...
3964  open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
3964  open("/root/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3964  open("/dev/shm/ecryptfs-root-Private", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW, 0600) = 3
3964  open("/root/.ecryptfs/Private.sig", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3964  +++ exited with 1 +++
3954  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3964, si_uid=0, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
3954  +++ exited with 1 +++
```

As we can see, it can't find a file `Private.sig` of **root**; it looks like it should be ran by user who encrypted directory we are trying to recover instead of running in a particular directory.

All in all, I ran this command(entered login password) with user's rights:

```
strace -o /tmp/strace3.log -f -e trace=file ecryptfs-mount-private`
```

Part of contents of `/tmp/strace3.log` file:

```
...
4137  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
4137  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
4137  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
4137  open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
4137  open("/home/user/.ecryptfsrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
4137  open("/home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
4137  open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
4137  +++ exited with 1 +++
4112  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4137, si_uid=1000, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
...
```

As we can see now, an `ecryptfs-mount-private` utility can't access user's `wrapped-passphrase` file which resulted in **Permission denied** message.

Checked `/home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` file's permissions and they were:

```
-rw------- 1 root root
```

Changed owner of this file via `sudo chown user:user /home/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` to user and reran above (`ecryptfs-mount-private`) command without strace(entered login password) which resulted in **success** message:

```
INFO: Your private directory has been mounted.
INFO: To see this change in your current shell:
  cd: /home/user
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that search results will show this question has an accepted answer.

Comment: @L.Levrel Thank you, but, unfortunately, I can't. It shows "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"